# Can this lattice be realized as an intermediate subgroups lattice?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, lattice-orders, gap

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ a subgroup.
Let $\mathcal{L}(H \subset G )$ be  the lattice of all the intermediate subgroups between $H$ and $G$.

Let the lattice $\mathcal{L}$ as follows:

[image]

**Question:** Can $\mathcal{L}$ be realized as an intermediate subgroups lattice?

*Remark*: I've checked by GAP that there is no example for $[G:H]<32$.

Comment: The subgroups having same level has same index ?

Comment: @mesel: not necessarily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The first example was given by Aschbacher in the following 2008 paper (example 8.5).

> Aschbacher, Michael. *On intervals in subgroup lattices of finite groups.* J. Amer. Math. Soc. 21 (2008), no. 3, 809–830. [link](http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2008-21-03/S0894-0347-08-00602-4/home.html)

Before this paper, Watatani (1994) had proven that with two possible exceptions, any finite lattice with $\leq 6$ elements could be realized as an intermediate subfactor lattice. In the paper above Aschbacher finds examples for these two lattices.

Comment: Nice thank you!  Watatani's paper is about subfactors which is more general than inclusions of groups. Some of the lattices in the paper of Watatani are realized by "adding chain" which is a subfactor theoretic process, I don't know if they admit realizations as intermediate subgroups lattices.

Comment: In the example 8.5, $H=A_6 \times A_6$, but what is $G$ explicitly?

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux: No idea, I only know about this result and have never looked at this paper in any detail. But see 8.1 and section 7 where $G$ is defined.